# How Do I Do Content Defined Breakpoints for this treehouse project?

Tags: css

So I was asked to write a media query at 705px where the layout begins to break, that forces grid_1 through grid_6 to span 100% width of the container.

I initially went to the bottom of my css file and typed in the following code

```
@ media screen and (max-width: 705px) {

.grid_1,
.grid_2,
.grid_3,
.grid_4,
.grid_5,
.grid_6, {
    width:100%;
} 

}
```

Here is the rest of the relevant code for the project.

```
.grid_1 { width: 15.625%; } /* 125px/800px = 15.625% */
.grid_2 { width: 32.5%; } /* 260px/800px = 32.5% */
.grid_3 { width: 49.375%; } /* 395px/800px = 49.375% */
.grid_4 { width: 65.625%; } /* 525px/800px = 65.625% */
.grid_5 { width: 83.125%; } /* 665px/800px = 83.125% */
.grid_6 { width: 100%; } /* 800px/800px = 100% */

.grid_1,
.grid_2,
.grid_3,
.grid_4,
.grid_5,
.grid_6 {
    margin-right: 1.25%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
.alpha { margin-left:0; }
.omega {margin-right:0; }

.container{
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 800px;
    padding: 4% 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: You're supposed to put the code in exactly the place where it says "enter code here" (and thus remove the whole "enter code here" text). An alternative is to paste the code unmodified, and then **select** it, and then press the `{}` button in editor (or the Ctrl+K key) while having the code still selected. Below the post editor, you can see a realtime preview of how it will ultimately be formatted. Also pay attention to that and make sure that your question looks decent. You can press the "edit" link below the question to edit and fix your post.

Comment: 'enter code here' made my day :D

Comment: Haha, yeah I knew it looked silly, but I hadn't figured it out at the time. I like the select all and Ctrl+K option. I've got it figured out now. Thanks man

Comment: +1 for Marty McVry for cleaning that ! (not an easy task)